# Boundary of a Borel set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $B$ is a Borel set of this space, i.e. $B\in\mathcal{B}(X)$ where $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains all open subsets of $X$.

Let $B\subset A$ where $A$ is compact. Is it true that $A' = (A\setminus B) \cup\partial B$ is a compact set?

If it is not true in general, does it hold if $X$ is also metrizable (separable)?

Finally, is a condition that $B$ is a Borel set is crucial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unwinding the definition, one can see that $A' = A \backslash B^\circ$, where $B^\circ$ is the interior of $B$.  A compact set minus an open set is always compact; this is an easy exercise.  (Contrary to a previous edit, it isn't necessary to assume that $A$ is closed or that $X$ is Hausdorff.)   No other assumptions on $A,B,X$ are needed.

Comment: Do you use here that $B^\circ = B\setminus \partial B$?

Comment: @Gortaur: Yes, the interior of a set is the set itself minus its boundary.